# RDP connects but authentication fails

Tags: windows-7, rdp

I have a couple of workstations that always fail authentication when I try to connect to them with RDP. The server and client configuration appears to be identical.

There was a Schannel error

> A fatal error occurred when attempting to access the SSL server
>   credential private key. The error code returned from the cryptographic
>   module is 0x8009030d. The internal error state is 10001.

Which I resolved(?) by changing the permissions on the CA assigned certificates to allow read access by the NETWORK SERVICE account.

Certificates all appear valid and I cannot see anything to indicate a fault in the application/system/security event logs.

All credentials fail to authenticate, not even the local administrator.

Does anyone have any ideas?

**Summary of suggestions**

- Check date/time sync. (checked okay)
- Change schannel logging verbosity (changed, unable to identify anything unusual)

**Update 1**

Enabled Debug/Analytic logging on `TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager` using `wevtutil` tool.

> wevtutil sl Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager/Analytic /e:true
>   wevtutil sl Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager/Debug /e:true

The Debug logs show some errors.

> TERMSRV: ERR::IConnection->Accept failed: 0xd000020f in CListenerEx::TransferWorkItem
>
> TERMSRV: ERR::ptrExt->AcceptConnection failed: 0xd000020f in CConnectionEx::Accept

**Update 2**

I ran procmon during an attempt to authenticate. I couldn't find any issues.

I tried resetting the TCP/IP stack using `netsh winsock reset` and `netsh int ip reset` (this seems to fix inexplicable weirdness).

After a reboot the interface would not get configured with DHCP no matter what I tried. This machine was a VM so I just added a new nic and removed the old one.

Interestingly enough after this step the interface configured and RDP is now working on this machine.

I tried the netshell resets on another affected machine and although the interface successfully reconfigured after boot RDP is still failing authentication.

Maybe the problem is tied to the nic mac address...

**Update 3**

There is a physical machine that has identical symptoms as the VM, all logs so far show the same.

The problem still remains after:

- resetting netshell
- removing the nic device and adding again
- changing the nic mac address
- adding a completely new physical nic!

Comment: Is the system date and time on all involved systems correct?

Comment: @joeqwerty yep, the domain NTP service appears to be working properly on the affected machines as well as the unaffected machines

Comment: Turn up the SCHANNEL logging: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee406184.aspx

Comment: @RyanRies I have increased verbosity for schannel to level 4. When I attempt to create a RDP session I see normal and expected TLS negotiation. Do you have anything specific you think I should look for?

Comment: Meh. I had a feeling that might happen. Sorry. How about a packet capture. Also, have you installed KB2992611?

Comment: @RyanRies Because encapsulated with TLS I wont get much from packet cap. Do you know if there is a way to increase the logging verbosity of the remote desktop/terminal server service?

Comment: @RyanRies KB2992611 seems to be a million years old. This problem seems to have occurred within the last week. It does not appear to be correlated with any installed updates.

Comment: With a packet capture, I was wanting to see whether we'd at least see a client hello and a server hello and whether a cipher was negotiated, etc.  You can do this even without a MitM. If we don't get that, then our issue occurs somewhere else other than Schannel.

Comment: @RyanRies Ah okay. The schannel logging indicates the cipher negotiation was successful. I will have a look at a packet cap to see if I can see the same. (Proto: TLS 1.2, CipherSuite: 0xc028, Exch Strength: 256)

Comment: have you reviewed this?  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2012/10/07/error-hresult-0x80070520-when-adding-ssl-binding-in-iis.aspx

Comment: @user2320464 thanks, I had a read. It looks to refer to ssl/tls binding to iis sites. So far logging indicates that tls is successfully negotiated and established. I am not sure if I have missed something here.

Comment: The schannel error is related to certificates which should not allow the connection to be established. If you're able to get to the logon screen and fail to login, then that is an entirely different problem. Instead of saying "RDP won't connect" it should read "RDP connects but authentication fails"

Comment: @user2320464 fair point. I will change that.

Comment: @Ablue Thanks! Please also include relevant events indicating failed logon events.

Comment: @user2320464 at this stage there are no auth fail events. The only failure events i can see are on the debug logs i have posted

Comment: Silly question from me, but I must ask, do you got a AV or anything like a firewall from the AV that is enabled in you tcpip stack ? You can validate in your tcpip property windows too, as some AV install somrthing even if no firewall from them is activated.

Comment: @yagmoth555 doesn't seem like a silly question. There is AV on these machines. The same AV that is on all machines. The policy is centrally managed and they are all in-line with current policy. I can try removing/disabling the AV but logs so far indicate to me that comms do not appear to be a problem (excludes FW?).

Comment: The second System Event log example in this article seems to describe your problem exactly - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2014/10/22/rdp-fails-with-event-id-1058-event-36870-with-remote-desktop-session-host-certificate-ssl-communication/

Comment: @joeqwerty It makes sense. I will try changing the file permissions on those key files. At any rate it give me another tool to examine the failure. I can use procmon to get more info if changing ACLs doesn't work. Why not add this as an answer?

Comment: Well, I really didn't have a clue. I was just Googling around because it's an interesting problem. If you find that it does solve the problem then I may add it as an answer... or you can self-answer the question since you're the one doing the real work of solving the issue. At any rate, good luck with it.

Comment: @joeqwerty I examined the ACLs for this key file and they match the ACLs in that document already. :(

Comment: I'd guess that SChannel was misconfigured on the old interface. Giving the VM a new interface reset SChannel.

Comment: @JoelCoel That doesn't seem impossible, as to *how* it was misconfigured, I have nothing...

Comment: @JoelCoel Adding a new nic has not fixed the problem on the physical machine. The same logical steps were taken, but the result was different.

Comment: Can you isolate the OU where the computer are to allow no GPO on them, just to be sure the machine state is clean

Comment: @yagmoth555 great suggestion :) I will give it a shot. It may take a little while though, I have spend a while trying to fix it I have opted to just run up a replacement workstation. I will do some experiments on the haunted machine in isolation. Interesting the affected machines are all in different OUs with OS of Win 7 PRO (32bit), Win 7 Ent (64bit), Win Srv 2008 (32bit). Not much in common except they are not standard and most of our workstations are Win 7 Pro (64bit).

Answer (score 0):

Under Administrative Tools > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration, right click on the server configuration object (presented in the middle of the screen) and go to Properties > Security (click through the warning) and make sure **BUILTIN\Remote Desktop Users** are granted all access BUT Full Control. Also ensure **BUILTIN\Administrators** are granted full control.

Someone changed these settings on us for Server 2008 R2 and that caused this same issue.